# Excluding a Django app from being localized using a middleware

Tags: python, django, localization, django-middleware

I need to localize a django project, but keep one of the applications (the blog) English only.

I wrote this middleware in order to achieve this:

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.core.urlresolvers import resolve

class DelocalizeMiddleware:
    def process_request(self, request):
        current_app_name = __name__.split('.')[-2]
        match = resolve(request.path)
        if match.app_name == current_app_name:
            request.LANGUAGE_CODE = settings.LANGUAGE_CODE
```

Problem is, it assumes the middleware lies directly in the application module (e.g. ***blog/middleware.py***) for retrieving the app name. Other projects might have the middleware in ***blog/middleware/delocalize.py*** or something else altogether.

What's the best way to retrieve the name of the currently running app?

Answer (score 1):

You can use Django's `resolve` function to get the current app name.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/urls/#resolve